# Ошибка read_csv в pandas

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

Когда я открываю датасет, он выводит ошибку, хотя я не вижу никаких проблем. Как мне это исправить?

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-76a26ffa0a27> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")## подключим файл

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    444 
    445     try:
--> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
    447     finally:
    448         parser.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1035 
-> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1037 
   1038         # May alter columns / col_dict

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1846     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1847         try:
-> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1849         except StopIteration:
   1850             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 396, saw 7
```

Датасет выглядит целым, и был надыблен из надежного источника. [Ссылка на .csv](https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=360181)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
fn = r'C:\download\data-9776-2018-10-24.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';', encoding='cp1251')
```

результат:

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
      Latitude_WGS84             Name     ...                                                geoData Unnamed: 14
0          55.756165  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.62338815, 55.7561...         NaN
1          55.745141  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.618774048, 55.745...         NaN
2          55.743325  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.615476946, 55.743...         NaN
3          55.741227  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.611919344, 55.741...         NaN
4          55.739825  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.60956385, 55.7398...         NaN
5          55.746453  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.618727711, 55.746...         NaN
6          55.744822  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.613575947, 55.744...         NaN
...              ...              ...     ...                                                    ...         ...
1425       55.730729  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.611766372, 55.730...         NaN
1426       55.739136  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.616166833, 55.739...         NaN
1427       55.738128  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.616791858, 55.738...         NaN
1428       55.733356  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.609650507, 55.733...         NaN
1429       55.759070  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.656035468, 55.759...         NaN
1430       55.782395  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.579823295, 55.782...         NaN
1431       55.745912  Городской Wi-Fi     ...      {type=Point, coordinates=[37.648522245, 55.745...         NaN

[1432 rows x 15 columns]
```